# Map Many-to-many relational table and show 0 if the data not exist in map table

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many

I have two table and one mapping table when the pivot between **TableA** and **TableB** is set.

Table A

```
+----+-------+
| Id | Level |
+----+-------+
|  1 | VIP1  |
|  2 | VIP2  |
|  3 | VIP3  |
|  4 | VIP4  |
| 5  | VIP5  |
+----+-------+
```

Table B

```
+----+----------+
| Id |   Name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Bank     |
|  2 | Online   |
|  3 | Transfer |
|  4 | Redeem   |
+----+----------+
```

Mapping Table

```
+----+---------+-----------+--------+
| Id | LevelId | TableBId  | Status |
+----+---------+-----------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |         1 |      0 |
|  2 |       1 |         2 |      1 |
|  3 |       2 |         3 |      1 |
|  4 |       5 |         1 |      0 |
|  5 |       5 |         2 |      1 |
|  6 |       5 |         3 |      1 |
+----+---------+-----------+--------+
```

I want to achieve something list this

```
+------+------+--------+----------+--------+
| Name | Bank | Online | Transfer | Redeem |
+------+------+--------+----------+--------+
| VIP1 |    0 |      1 |        0 |      0 |
| VIP2 |    0 |      0 |        1 |      0 |
| VIP3 |    0 |      0 |        0 |      0 |
| VIP4 |    0 |      0 |        0 |      0 |
| VIP5 |    0 |      0 |        1 |      0 |
+------+------+--------+----------+--------+
```

Here **TableA** and **TableB** is both dynamic and can be add at anytime in future.

i wanted to try by creating a view table. but i'm not getting an idea how to create it.

Comment: i don't want to hard code all the cases. is it possible to make it more dynamic?

Comment: *"Map Many-to-many relational table and show null if the data not exist in map table"* i don't see NULL in the expected results...  NULL and zero isn't the same thing in SQL.

Comment: Consider data display issues to be handled by application code if anny..

Comment: @RaymondNijland for null can show "0" instead of null sorry i'll update it

Comment: @RaymondNijland sorry i didn't get it what you mean. data display issue?